# cannot create temp file for here-document, installing ruby 1.9.2 with rvm

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, fedora, ruby-1.9.2

> rvm install 1.9.2

gives:

```
[2011-08-31 00:54:45]  ./configure --prefix=/home/pklingem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/home/pklingem/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir
./configure: line 2307: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2319: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2354: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2516: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2520: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2524: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2528: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2532: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
./configure: line 2536: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
./configure: line 3356: cannot create temp file for here-document: Invalid argument
checking whether the C compiler works... no
sed: can't read conftest.c: No such file or directory
configure: error: in `/home/pklingem/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I am running Fedora 16 Alpha.  That really (hopefully) shouldn't matter.  Has anyone else encountered this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your permissions for your /tmp folder are 1777 (octal).

Comment: you were probably right.  I ran some updates and reran the 1.9.2 setup and all is well.  Thanks!

Comment: You were definitely right.  I was playing around putting /tmp into tmpfs (RAM), and the guide I'd read suggested 1755, which rendered autocomplete in terminal useless...